# X11: move an existing window via command line?

Tags: x11

Given an X client window ID, is there a way to move that window or change its geometry from the command line?

```
$ xlsclients -a
Window 0x3000001:
  Machine:  ohm
  Name:  Terminal
  Icon Name:  foo
  Command:  foo
  Instance/Class:  foo/bar

$ xmovewindow -id 0x3000001 --geometry +100+200  <-- this is what I would like to do
```

Comment: To get the hex window id, I needed to use `xlsclients -l`, not -a  (Mac 10.15.7, XQuartz 2.8.1 (xorg-server 1.20.11), xlsclients 1.1.4)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) will do the job.

> xdotool lets you programatically (or manually) simulate keyboard input and mouse activity, move and resize windows, etc. It does this using X11's XTEST extension and other Xlib functions.

E.g.

```
$ xdotool windowfocus 0x1a00ad2
```

will focus the window with id 0x1a00ad2. There's also a windowmove command which is probably the one you're looking for.

[wmctrl](http://tripie.sweb.cz/utils/wmctrl/) is slighty more advanced. It is compatible with EWMH/NetWM X window managers as you can read on [their website](http://tripie.sweb.cz/utils/wmctrl/). I don't think you'll need it to be compatible with those though.

Comment: There's also DevilsPie, which uses libwnck; that also ought to be compatible with EWMH/NetWM window managers in general.

Comment: Great tool, I haven't knew about it ! Thanks !

Comment: As an example, the OP wanted to do something like `xmovewindow  -id 0x3000001 --geometry +100+200`, with wmctl that would be `wmctrl -i -r 0x3000001 -e 0,100,200,-1,-1`.

Comment: `wmctrl` is all you need! Great tool.