# X11: Setting a window undecorated or always-visible via command-line

Tags: command-line, x11

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1029027/710951) mentions the tools `xdotool` and `wmctrl` which are able to **change a window's geometry via the command-line**. This OK.

But, what if I want to do more advanced operations, for instance:

- Setting a window **undecorated**.
- Making a window **visible on all desktops** (omnipresent).
- Setting a window **always visible**.

Are there any tools allowing me to do the things avobe *from command-line*?
I use [Openbox](http://openbox.org/) as my window manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought:

> The window navigator of GNOME can do some of this actions, so it should use a library to achieve it.

Looking at his sources, I found it. It is the **Window Navigation Construction Kit** (wnck for short).
This C/C++ library is called `libwnck`, and the reference manual can be found [here](http://developer.gnome.org/libwnck/stable/).

But, as it's not a standalone tool, I will probably need to make a custom program to use it.  :-(
<sub>I will edit this answer if I found news, but you're welcome to post your answer if you found a tool!</sub>

---

**Edit:** Using the bindings for Python (`python-wnck`) it's easy to make a script achieve it.

Comment: if you gonna accept your own answer, saying that it is possible in python - maybe drop some python lines with an example

Comment: Hi! You're right, unfortunately I no longer have the code I made. But it should be easy to get a working example by installing `python-wnck` and playing around with the `wnck` module.

Comment: Once you install `python-wnck` you can find examples of use in [`/usr/share/doc/python-wnck/examples`](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.apt-browse.org%2Fbrowse%2Fubuntu%2Ftrusty%2Fmain%2Fi386%2Fpython-wnck%2F2.32.0%2Bdfsg-3%2Ffile%2Fusr%2Fshare%2Fdoc%2Fpython-wnck%2Fexamples%2Fwnck_example.py&oq=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.apt-browse.org%2Fbrowse%2Fubuntu%2Ftrusty%2Fmain%2Fi386%2Fpython-wnck%2F2.32.0%2Bdfsg-3%2Ffile%2Fusr%2Fshare%2Fdoc%2Fpython-wnck%2Fexamples%2Fwnck_example.py`). The module only works on Python 2.

Answer (score 7):

`wmctrl` can set the on-all-desktops and always-on-top properties using the `-b` option (the specific properties are `sticky` and `above`, respectively)