# Close all open X-windows with a command in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, x11

I have variable stand alone shell routines which I execute one after another automatically. Since every routine produces several X-windows figures I want to close all of them at the end without modifying every single routine. Is there a certain command?

Cheers!

Comment: As a side thing, closing only specific ones would be a nice thing, too.

Answer (score 2):

Based on answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1029027/274350). [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) looks like what you need.

To kill an X11 window given it's title, you can use:

```
xdotool search "Your window title here" windowkill
```

Comment: From the manpage: `windowclose` will close the window but not kill the controlling application, `windowkill` will kill the controlling application. So, `windowclose` will act like hitting the "close"-button on the window and the application can exit nicely, `windowkill` will be more like `xkill`. More refined search for window names I get with `xlsw` instead of `xdotool`, example: `xlsw | grep 'Firefox/Popup' | awk '{print $1}' | while read i; do xdotool windowclose "$i"; done`; `xdotool search` would miss the `/Popup`-part in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Windows are owned by processes. One way to close windows is to kill their owner processes.

Another way is to start another X server, run your scripts with `DISPLAY` environment variable referring to the display of that X server, then terminate that X server with all windows.