# Bash send string to stdin of process

Tags: string, bash, inter-process-communicat

I need to send string to stdin and display it on the screen

```
/proc/$pid$/fd/0
```

But it works only in console-based progams(cat, nano, etc). How to send it to GUI application?

Comment: Can you provide more specifics about what you are doing to write to the specified file, then more specifics about what you want sent to a GUI application (existing, new, REST call, etc etc etc).

Comment: The same way. stdin doesn't care about if the program is GUI, text-mode, or no UI at all. I'm pretty sure this is a XY problem - explain what you want to achieve and there may be a different way altogether to handle it.

Comment: Your GUI program probably doesn't read from its standard input.

Answer (score 0):

You will need identify the window in the system and inject them the keyboard events with a tool like "xdotool".

See this question as reference: [X11: move an existing window via command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029027/x11-move-an-existing-window-via-command-line)