# Can I change the my terminal position by using either the command line or perl?

Tags: linux, perl, terminal, position, window

I'm running several background processes while I monitor another screen. I usually resize a terminal window for the background processes and place it on the far right of my screen and then run a perl script. I've added a system call to `resize -s ## ##` to resize the window automaticcaly but is there a way to also adjust the window location? Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends on window manager and/or installed window manipulation tools. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029027/x11-move-an-existing-window-via-command-line

Answer (score 3):

If

```
resize -s row col
```

works, then likely other parts of the escape sequence repertoire of xterm (in this case adapted from dtterm) are implemented.  In this section

```
CSI Ps ; Ps ; Ps t
          Window manipulation (from dtterm, as well as extensions by
          xterm).  These controls may be disabled using the allowWin-
          dowOps resource.
```

[XTerm Control Sequences](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Ps;Ps;Ps-t:Ps-=-3;x;y.216C) lists this one:

```
        Ps = 3 ;  x ;  y -> Move window to [x, y].
```

which you could use by

```
printf '\033[3;%d;%dt' $x $y
```

in a shell script, with *`$x`* and *`$y`* being the x/y coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question completely but some processes like background processes can be skipped with no tty by using the nohup command. But of course this can depend on what that process is and it can be resumed with fg.