# Open a program by terminal in the middle of the screen in Gnome 3?

Tags: pdf, terminal, window, gnome-shell

I am trying to open a pdf using Zathura by terminal, but it opens at the size that Gnome 3 considers.

My goal is to automatically place it divided to the right. To open it the script is something like this:

```
zathura MyFile.pdf
```

And it shows this:
[image: Image Open Estandar]
My goal is for it to open as follows:
[image: Image Open Spliteed]
Is this possible using only the terminal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*(taken from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1029302/2921914))*

You have 2 options:

If you *only* need it to work in an X session, then this is relatively easy to do using xdotool (short summary in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1029302/2921914)).

The Wayland protocol does not allow this by default for security reasons. If you want to be able to support both X and Wayland, you'll have to get to the inner working of GNOME Shell by [installing an extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/) (you can find several that are related) or by [writing one yourself](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions/Writing).